# Issue with importing rest_framework inside django app

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am facing an issue of importing rest_framework inside my django app whenever i try to make migrations or create superuser or simply run the runserver.
I have installed the framework using this command but django still doesn't recognize it

sudo pip install djangorestframework

here's the snippet of settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'companies.apps.CompaniesConfig',
]


 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
    'rest_framework.serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer',

# Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
# or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
]
}
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/tam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364       
in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "/home/tam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
django.setup()
File "/home/tam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/tam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/tam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages   
/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/home/tam/Canopy/appdata/canopy-1.7.4.3348.rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/  
importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named rest_framework
```

Comment: first, don't use sudo to install python pip packages unless you know what you're doing.  second, you're apparently using an anaconda environment.  did you install DRF with that environment activated?

Comment: i use sudo because pip commands sometimes don't work perfectly without it. Also i am not using anaconda environment. i have enthought canopy installed.

Comment: ok, then make sure `rest_framework`  is in that site pckages folder at `/home/tam/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.  If its not there, its not installed

Comment: Please don't mess with sudo pip install. Learn how to use virtualenv and that would help fixing your issue. "sudo pip install" just installed drf in another python environment so no wonder it can't find it.